# How to call multiple scenes in scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Hi i have created two scenes for my game .one scene is empty scene without any collada .dae file and other scene is with collada file how can i call two scenes at a time in scenekit.`For example code bellow

```
let scene1 = SCNScene()
let scene2 = SCNScene(named:"art.scnassets/hero.dae")
```

i want my hero should be in scene1 as my scene1 is main scene of the application
the movement of hero should follow my first main scene . Someone know how to do this?

`

Comment: Please make clear what you are trying to achieve, because your question is really unclear

Comment: my question is that i have an empty scene in which i have created a 3D map with planes and now a want to add a colleda file in my scene in viewcontroller using an other scene

Comment: It appears you already have solved this in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36539980/719690.

Comment: Yes i solved but the problem is still with character movement whenever i touch to move my character it does not move it just jump and go out that is the problem i am trying to ask actually